# how do i legitimately change filename value of ofstream object?

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm having troubles with `ofstream` , which is - when I change value of `ofstream` object like this

```
ofstream o_save; 

/*code*/

o_save = ofstream(filename);  //Problem is here
```

...the line above completely erase contents of file.

The question is how do I legitimately change `filename` value of `ofstream` object ?

P.S. I cant define it when I declare it, because I want it global and I'm not sure which save file I select.

Comment: Use `o_save.open("file.txt", ios::app)` to open and then close using `o_save.close()`. Open another one after that.

Comment: Just opening a file for writing should not "completely erase contents of the file". It simply opens the file so you yourself can overwrite the contents of it. If you want to append to the file then change the [open mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).

Comment: Also, you can not simply "change the filename" once you opened the file. It seems like you have to think a little bit more about the design of our program, and what you want to accomplish with it.

Comment: The question is vague in itself. The title talks about changing filename and the content talks of saving file's contents.
@user1849353 what exactly do you want?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "Just opening a file for writing" does truncate it.  One could argue that it shouldn't, but the standard requires it.

Comment: `ofsteram` objects do not have filename values, so the question is ill formed. Voting to close.

Comment: @JamesKanze Oh, okay. But then what use is the `trunc` open mode for?

Comment: You really don't "want it global". You want to give your saving functions an `ostream &` argument instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg To empty a file if you're opening for both reading and writing.  I agree that it isn't very useful.  And that the open flags in general aren't very orthogonal or coherent---they're designed to map easily to `fopen` modes, rather than to be logical.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ah yes, seeing the table with the open-modes and their corresponding `fopen` modes in the standard now. The only time one needs the `trunc` flags is for the `"w+"` `fopen` mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is quite vague and contradictory, and the OP seems to have slept after asking the question. So I shall try to peek inside his head and try to elaborate what he wants.

For opening a file, there are many [modes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) for that. Open it like this.

```
ofstream o_value ;
o_value.open("file.txt") ;
```

If you want to preserve the original contents of that file, use..

```
o_value.open("file.txt", ios::app) ;
```

If you want to close it later and open another one, close using...

```
o_value.close() ;
```

Chaning of file names is normally not allowed in case of `ofstream`. You can use `rename` from `<cstdlib>`. You can delete a file though using `remove("file.txt")` in `<cstdio>` .

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean to "change the name" of an `ofstream` object?
The only "name" an `ofstream` object has is the name of the
variable.  An `ofstream` object is a data stream.  You can (on
some systems) change the name of the file it is associated with,
using `rename`, but somehow, I don't think this is what you want
either.  You can also close the stream, and reopen it on another
file.

You cannot assign between iostream objects.  If worse comes to
worse, you can declare the global object as a pointer, and
assign to it (using `*o_save` to write to it).

Finally, the standard says that when you open an `ofstream`, you
truncate the file, if one exists.  If this is not what you want
to do, then you have to add some flags to the open mode.  If you
add `std::ios_base::app`, for example, you will no longer
truncate the file, and all writes will be to the end of file
(atomically, if the system supports it).  Alternatively (albeit
quite surprising), you could add `std::ios::in` to the flags;
this will fail if the file doesn't exist, but will allow writing
anywhere in the file.  This is the only way to open a file for
writing if you want to be able to write anywhere in the file,
even if you don't want to read it.

Answer (score 0):

The `ofstream` does not have some kind of an abstract `name` attribute, the name is just a parameter to some of its member functions, in that sense asking how to

> change `filename` value of `ofstream` object

is meaningless.

In general you can rename files with `std::rename` from `<cstdlib>` or use Boost.Filesystem.